# How should percent values be returned using with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two possible ways to return a percent:

A) Returning the actual percent (100 * value) = 55.00

B) Returning as decimal = 0.55

I started using approach (A) but I notice that the c# format string for percent will multiply the original value by 100. What is the best practice for returning percent values in sql and drawbacks/reasons to either approaches?

Comment: There is no correct answer, It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Formatting values for display is generally best left to the application, not handled by the database. A value could be displayed as percent, quartile, slice on a pie chart, or applied as a discount or surcharge. As such, I'd just let the database handle it as a decimal value and let the application handle the rest as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing calculations based on said percentage, you'll want to store it as the decimal value such as:

Take aValue as 100, and aPercent as 55 like your post:

```
select aValue * aPercent from myTable
```

(returns 0.55)

However, if you'll just be holding these and returning the value, or concatenate as part of a string, it would make sense to store it as a whole number or string so for SQL server:

```
select convert(varchar(6),aPercent) + '%' from myTable
```

(returns '55%')

Whatever means less code writing, and less processing is what I'd go for.